# Does a change in web.appsettings.config triggers an Application Pool recycle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, application-pool

I have an ASP.NET application with Web.appSettings.config.
Exactly in web.config I have included this line:

```
<appSettings configSource="Web.appSettings.config" />
```

and in web.appSettings.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="foo" value="foo value" />
</appSettings>
```

I have tested it myself. If I change something web.config the IIS App pool recycles. But seems that if I change something in web.appSettings.config it doesn't recycle.

**Changes in web.appSettings.config... are supposed to trigger an Application Pool recycle?**

**Is there any official Microsoft link that clarifies it?**

CLARIFICATION: My tests shows that changes in web.appSettings.config shows that no app pool recycle is triggered. My doubt is about expected behavior. **Is it normal that app pool doesn't recycle or is there something wrong with my IIS..?**

Comment: afaik only changes in web.config file fire app pool recycle (this behavior can be altered). The changes in related files (defined through configSource) don't trigger recycling.

Comment: My tests seems to indicate the same but I didn't found any link on MSDN or similar to confirm it so I am not 100% sure

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx

Comment: In that link explains that changes in web.config triggers a recycle but doesn't clarify if changes web.appsettings.config (or similar) should trigger or not a recycle...

Comment: It lists all the things that DO cause a recycle. It also doesn't mention whether a recycle will happen during a full moon, doesn't mean your IIS is broken :)

Comment: Seems that you can force this behaviour by using [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "web.appsettings.config", Watch = true)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

But instead of relying an answer from here, I would test it myself.

For example; when the application pool recycles, it means your application will restart. Put a breakpoint in your Application_Start event in global.asax. Update web.config, make a request to your page and see if it hits. Then update web.appsettings.config file and try the same. In the second case the breakpoint should not hit.

You can also understand it by logging the events (or probably checking existing IIS logs etc.) as well.

Comment: I tested it myself (Edited question to make it more clear). I know for sure that in my case it doesn't recycle app pool. What I am not sure is if it is the expected behavior or is there something wrong with my IIS...

Comment: Yep, now it's more clear and understandable suspicion. For my part, I had the same case while ago and had to be sure whether it's causing a reset and it wasn't - so, we can say it's an expected behavior (of course unless both of our IIS's are broken :o)

Comment: both IIS brokens are unlikely. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Changes in Web.config triggers an AppDomain recycle, not an AppPool recycle.